# Jenkins…Access XML Tag value in xml file using Groovy in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using groovy script for automated deployment in jenkins.

In have a xml file, I want to read specific xml tag value from that xml file and  assign it's value to a variable. Letter I am using that variable to write excel file. Below is the script. After executing the build it seems that I am not able to access the xml tag value. It seems the code inside of each function is not working. Can anyone please help me on this

```
def Build_Name= ""
def Build_Number= ""
def CR_Number=""
def Build_Status= ""
def Build_Failure_Reason=""
def Build_Date=""

Build_Number= "1201"
CR_Number="123"
Build_Status= "SUCCESS"
Build_Failure_Reason="NA"
Build_Date=""
boolean fileSuccessfullyDeleted =  new File("/export/home/webm/.jenkins/Build_Report.csv").delete()
f = new File("/export/home/webm/.jenkins/Build_Report.csv")

def Job_Result_file = new File("/export/home/webm/.jenkins/global-build-stats/jobresults/Temp_Job_Result.xml")
//Parse it with XmlSlurper
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(Job_Result_file)


xml.list.jbr.each { sd ->
                 Build_Name= sd.n[0].value
f.append("\r\n"+Build_Name+","+Build_Number+","+CR_Number+","+Build_Status+","+Build_Failure_Reason+","+Build_Date+"")



}
```

**EDIT: based on OP added as answer.**

Below is the xml available in xml file and I want to read the value of tag and want to assign that value to a variable. In below xml tag n has value Send_Deployment_Request.

Xml:

```
<list>
 <jbr plugin="global-build-stats@1.4">
    <r>SUCCESS</r>
    <n>Send_Deployment_Request</n>
    <nb>187</nb>
    <d>
      <time>1502879887698</time>
      <timezone></timezone>
    </d>
    <du>973</du>
    <nn>master</nn>
    <un></un>
  </jbr>
  <jbr plugin="global-build-stats@1.4">
    <r>SUCCESS</r>
    <n>Deploy</n>
    <nb>187</nb>
    <d>
      <time>1502879887698</time>
      <timezone></timezone>
    </d>
    <du>973</du>
    <nn>master</nn>
    <un></un>
  </jbr>
</list>
```

Dear Rao,
Please see my code below.

```
//Delete if Build_Report fiile already exist
boolean fileSuccessfullyDeleted =  new File("/export/home/webmadm/.jenkins/Build_Report.csv").delete()

//Craete new csv file
f = new File("/export/home/webmadm/.jenkins/Build_Report.csv")

def Job_Result_file = new File("/export/home/webmadm/.jenkins/global-build-stats/jobresults/Temp_Job_Result.xml")

 def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(Job_Result_file)

 //Change the element name if needed

 def Temp_Build_Name= "n"
  def Temp_Build_Number= "nb"
   def CR_Number=""
   def Temp_Build_Status= "r"
   def Build_Failure_Reason=""
   def Temp_Build_Date="time"
   def Temp_Build_Executor="un"



def  Build_Name= ""
  def Build_Number= ""

   def Build_Status= ""

   def Build_Date=""
   def Build_Executor=""



    //Get all the values of Tag - elementToFind 
    def Build_Name_List= xml.'**'.findAll{'it.name() == Temp_Build_Name'}
    def Build_Number_List= xml.'**'.findAll{'it.name() == Temp_Build_Number'}
    def Build_Status_List= xml.'**'.findAll{'it.name() == Temp_Build_Status'}
    def Build_Date_List= xml.'**'.findAll{'it.name() == Temp_Build_Date'}
    def Build_Executor_List= xml.'**'.findAll{'it.name() == Temp_Build_Executor'}

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
          Build_Name= Build_Name_List[i].text()
          Build_Number= Build_Number_List[i].text()
          Build_Status= Build_Status_List[i].text()
          Build_Date= Build_Date_List[i].text()
          Build_Executor= Build_Executor_List[i].text()

            f.append("\r\n"+Build_Name+","+Build_Number+","+CR_Number+","+Build_Status+","+Build_Failure_Reason+","+Build_Date+"")

    }
```

I am trying to write .csv file. If you see f.append as per that in csc we have Build_Name value , Build_Number value and so on.

But actul result is different, Build_Name also contain the Build_Number, Build_Status Build_Date. Seems .findAll method reading entire tag  from xml.

Can't we use .each method as we use it to update the xml node value in xml file 
?

Comment: Show your xml and what data you need to read?

Comment: Please check the answer and see if that helps.

Comment: Dear Rao, I edited my question and put code.. Could you please check and provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you would need  and comments in-line:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(Job_Result_file)

//Change the element name if needed
def elementToFind = 'n'

//Get all the values of Tag - elementToFind 
def result = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == elementToFind}
println result

//Get the first item from the result
def requiredValue = result[0].text() 
println "User required value : $requiredValue"

//Test if the value is as expected
assert 'Send_Deployment_Request' == requiredValue
```

You can quickly see it online <kbd>[demo](http://ideone.com/OSAU6A)</kbd>

Comment: Dear Rao,it's giving me the value of all tag not a specific tag.

Comment: Is there any change in the xml? Have you checked the demo?

Comment: There is no change in xml. I can see the expected value in demo however  when I execute this code in my environment it give value of all tha xml tag

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: It print   SUCCESSSend_Deployment_Request1871502879887698973master    This is nothing but contain all the xml tag value

Comment: Please try commenting. `print result`

Comment: Dear Rao, I also tried with commenting print,. I think findAll is not the method to take the value of specific tag.

Comment: Remove quotes inside `findAll{'it.name() == Temp_Build_Name'}`. change to `findAll{it.name() == Temp_Build_Name}`

Comment: Without quotes I am getting error " no such class property for it". I am running this script in Jenkin project.